Where does the name of the Amsterdam variation in classical dragon come from?
After what (event?) is this variation in Classical dragon named Amsterdam variation and, if known, who first used that name?
[Title ""]
[Fen ""]
[Startply "15"]

1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 d6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 Nf6 5. Nc3 g6 6. Be2 Bg7 7. Be3 Nc6 8. Qd2 *

